# Why does chrome never delete google.com localstorage?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, tracking, local-storage

I have selected the "Keep local data only until I quit my browser" option in Chrome settings under Content Settings -> Cookies.

When I exit Chrome, I can see that every website file in my Local Storage directory is deleted. All of them except for "https_www.google.com_0.localstorage" and "https_www.google.com_0.localstorage-journal".

So, I have two questions:

1) Why? This does not seem fair to other websites.

2) What is the best way to disable this insidious behavior?

Thank You.

**UPDATE-1**: Here is what I'm doing for now. I created a batch file with the following contents and I simply use that to launch Chrome:

```
del "%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\*.google.com_0.localstorage"

del "%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\*.google.com_0.localstorage-journal"

start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```